# What is the difference between [column] and Table.Column(Table, "column") in M/PowerBI/PowerQuery

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

Ciao there!

I have a problem with a difference between [column] and [Table.Column(Table, "column")](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-column) in M/PowerBI/PowerQuery.

---

Example Table:
'#____column
1_______a
2_______b
3_______c

Desired Result:
'#____column
1_______TEST
2_______TEST
3_______TEST

---

So, I currently have the following code:

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(PrevQueryTable, each Table.Column(PrevQueryTable, "column"), 
            "TEST", 
        Replacer.ReplaceValue, {"column"})
```

which does not work. Result:

'#____column
1_______a
2_______b
3_______c

---

This however:

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(PrevQueryTable, each [column], 
            "TEST", 
        Replacer.ReplaceValue, {"column"})
```

does work. Result:

'#____column
1_______TEST
2_______TEST
3_______TEST

---

Why? And how can I make sth. like the first do work?
(Currently writing a function which uses this with column names as strings.)

Comment: I think it would help if you gave an example before and after replacement. I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Table.Column` returns a list from taking one table column.

`[column]` returns the value in that column *for the current row*.

In this case, I find `Table.TransformColumns` more flexible than `Table.ReplaceValue`.

If you used the GUI to transform several columns to UPPERCASE it would generate code that looks like this:

```
= Table.TransformColumns(
    PrevQueryTable,
    {{"Col1", Text.Upper, type text},
     {"Col2", Text.Upper, type text},
     {"Col3", Text.Upper, type text}})
```

This can serve as a template for how we want to write our own transformation. Suppose we have a list of column names `ColumnList` (from `Table.ColumnNames` for example). We could transform that list by adding the transformation functions to each element like so:

```
= Table.TransformColumns(
    PrevQueryTable,
    List.Transform(
        ColumnList,
        each {_, each "TEST", type text}
    )
  )
```

E.g. `"col1"` gets transformed into `{"col1", each "TEST", type text}`

Comment: So, I can't combine each with Table.Column().
And thanks for the List.Transform hint!

Do you know of any way to make functions like Table.ReplaceValue work within a function with parameters? My Problem with this is, that it takes the parameters
(Table, some code usually using each [col], some code usually using each [col], Replacer, "col-name-as-text")

And I don't like to build my function with parameters like (Column as column, ColumnName as text )

There should be a more elegant solution to refering to a column, that I'm missing.

Comment: Also added another Q for that.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60889219/how-can-i-loop-trough-elements-in-columns-in-a-powerbi-function