# M code to prepend values across multiple columns

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, m

I am sourcing a data file in PowerBI, which contains text in all columns.  I want to prepend additional text, which I've stored in a variable, to all column contents except for the first column.  I am able to get the column names, but am stuck figuring out how to iterate over the names (e.g. transform each with `"http://my.site/" & [column_data]`).

```
let
   Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\results.xlsx"), true, true),
   results_Sheet = Source{[Item="results",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
   results_columns = Table.ColumnNames(results_Sheet),
   suffixes = List.RemoveItems(results_columns, {"left_column_name"})
   prefix = my_prefix_variable
   final_result = ???
in
   final_result
```

Comment: My answer to this question might give you an idea to try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60873036/what-is-the-difference-between-column-and-table-columntable-column-in-m-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have gone to List what prevents you to do further editing. Keep working with a table..
I would go with following: Keep first row (before making it a header), transform to Rows and add a column with a prefix:

```
let
   Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\results.xlsx"), true, true),
   results_Sheet = Source{[Item="results",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
   #"Kept First Rows" = Table.FirstN(Source,1),
   #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Kept First Rows"),
   #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Transposed Table", "Custom", each myPara &[Column1])
in
   #"Added Custom"
```